# The specified cryptographic algorithm is not supported on this platform in Glacier Upload

Tags: c#, windows-xp, amazon-glacier

We are facing a problem in uploading data to glacier on Windows XP machine. Below is the error message
"The specified cryptographic algorithm is not supported on this platform."

Error occur at line (for .net low level glacier API)

```
client.UploadMultipartPart(uploadMPUrequest);
```

and also while using high level API below is the code

```
string archiveId =   manager.Upload(vaultName,"name",archiveToUpload).ArchiveId;
```

On reading few links we came to know that windows XP does not support cryptography. But we have many clients running XP machine, is there any solution or  any hot fix for it.

I came across a hot fix while searching the error but it works for windows server machine and no luck for windows XP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used AWSDK version 2.3 and that solved the problem, but using the higher version had led to many namespace and used classes names changes in the code.

Answer (score 1):

Let say that your crypto algorithm is SHA256.

If you have access to the code, you can try to use SHA256Managed instead of SHA256CryptoServiceProvider.

The algorithm will be run by the framework instead of try to be run by the platform.

If you need performance, you can try the platform algorithm then the framework implemented one ([Thomas Dufour](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1294837/361177) solution):

```
    SHA256 hash;
    try
    {
        hash = new SHA256Cng( );
    }
    catch ( PlatformNotSupportedException )
    {
        hash = SHA256.Create( );
    }
```

An other solution has described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293905/sha256cryptoserviceprovider-and-related-possible-to-use-on-winxp) is to rename the cryptographic service in the registry.

In `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Cryptography\Defaults\Provider`, find the subkey named "Microsoft Enhanced RSA and AES Cryptographic Provider (Prototype)" and rename it to 
"Microsoft Enhanced RSA and AES Cryptographic Provider".

The system has to be a XP SP3.

Comment: I guess Galcier API uses SHA256 algorithm by default for calculating checksum, I cannot see it explicitly specified in the sample code. so that's how i cannot alter it.

Comment: If you guess right (and I think so), the registry trick should be the only solution. You just have to create the `.reg` file that modify the registry and give it to your customers :o)

Comment: the below error occurs at method uploadMultipartPart. this is in build method provided by amazon glacier API

Comment: at System.Security.Cryptography.CapiHashAlgorithm.In
itialize()
   at System.Security.Cryptography.CapiHashAlgorithm..ctor()
   at System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256CryptoServiceProvider..ctor()
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.DefaultRequest.get_ContentStreamHash()
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.Auth.AWS4Signer.Sign()
   at Amazon.Runtime.AmazonWebServiceClient.SignRequest(IRequest request, Abstra
ctAWSSigner signer, RequestMetrics metrics)
   at Amazon.Runtime.AmazonWebServiceClient.ConfigureRequest()
   at Amazon.Runtime.AmazonWebServiceClient.InvokeHelper(A